# Re-install system Google Play store

Tags: google-play-store, lucky-patcher

I tried installing a modded Play store using Lucky Patcher, but in the process it deleted the system app and didn't install the modded one.  I have tried installing it manually but it just can't work and crashes every time I want to download or update apps.

Can anyone help me out in installing the official Play store?

Answer (score 1):

The "Install Modded Play Store" dialog in Lucky Patcher also supports installing the unmodded Google Play store. To do this, open Lucky Patcher > Tools > Install modded Play Store > Original Play Store (select version). Make sure to uncheck "Install as a User App" before installing. Then reboot.

If it doesn't install right (or doesn't appear after reboot), you could try it manually. Go to Rebuild & Install > LuckyPatcher > Download, select PlayStore.apk (which was downloaded by installing the unmodded Play Store above), press "Install as a System App", and then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Just flash a GAPPS package available on xda. You can choose from a variety of packages, available on multiple versions of Android. See [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/tk-gapps-t3116347) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Play Store. Then convert it to the system app then reboot. That's all.

To convert, you can simply use ES File Explorer. With this option, first, uninstall the Play Store. Enable root explorer in the app dashboard. Still, in the dashboard, tap local and select device. Look for system, app, and there paste the Play Store APK file there that you have copied (so you first copy the Play Store APK before going to root explorer). Next reboot.

Or you can convert to a system app using any root app like Link2SD. Here you need to install the Play Store app, next you open Link2SD and select Play Store. Tap the more options button and tap convert to system app. After it is complete, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Lucky Patcher
2. Delete files from Lucky Patcher folder
3. Click on Tools
4. Click on Install Modded Play Store
5. Click on original, not on modded; this process takes time of 5 minutes.

Now you have your own Play Store.